# What windows version should I purchase?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installation

I have no clue about Windows, but I have heard that bought copies can only be installed a limited number of times - but it is not clear to me how many, and for which versions.

I need a Windows version, but I am not 100% sure how I will be using it.  I have roughly the following requirements:

- I upgrade my laptop regularly, and I would like to reinstall Windows whenever I get a new one
- I do not want an OEM version, since that is tied to the laptop that I buy it with (I think)
- I also would need to install a copy in a Virtual Machine (inside Ubuntu)
- I have two other desktop systems which I rarely use (second residence), but I would like to install Windows on them too
- I am ok if only one of the installations can be running at any one time

Is there any version of windows that will satisfy these requirements?

Basically, what I need is a Windows version that I can purchase and re-install whenever something changes in my environment, without worries of being stuck with a CD that I can not install anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, MS licensing doesn't really work that way - they want one license per machine. You can swap from machine to machine in a limited fashion, but you'd need to ring them every time you did, & they would quickly run out of patience.

Comment: @Tetsujin: So, I spend 200€ (or whatever, I have no clue about prices), install it on one machine, decide to wipe it out because I need something else installed there, and the original CD can not be installed anymore, even though no installed copy exists?

Comment: You can put it back on that machine with no issues, but not move it to another without a phone call to MS, which you will get away with once or twice, but if they spot a pattern, they'll stop it. They want one machine, one license. That's their model. Bearing in mind that most ready-built machines already come with a license, it's not usually an issue for most people.

Answer (score 4):

The main effect of the new policy is that a single licence can now apply to different devices. A device can also be a virtual desktop. Microsoft's not been keen on VDI before, but in a BYOD world a locked-down virtual desktop is a more desirable device.
All the above is about Windows 10.

You also may install (and buy) Windows 7 or 8, if you don't know yet whether you will take MS or not...

Comment: Thanks. Note: BYOD is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_your_own_device.

Comment: So you are suggesting to not install windows directly on the hardware, but on a virtual machine? What host OS? How will this affect things like drivers? Can I expect the VM to work seamlessly with all my hardware? I assume this very much depends on the host OS HW support

Comment: And another question: why would installing Windows 7 or 8 be better, regarding my requirements (be able to reinstall without issues). Are windows 7/8 reinstallable in other computers, no questions asked?

Comment: try to use virtual box. I use the win7 on this machine and really satisfied.